# Incompatible types of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, incomplete-type

Hi I have small app in android where Im using fragments with navigation drawer for menu. But now I want show in my fragments dialog popup window when user click on something and there I get these errors:

**MainActivity:**

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

First error I get on *fragment = new HomeFragment();* **>>incompatible types**.

Second error on HomeFragment at **onCreateView method** >> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

**HomeFragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends FragmentActivity {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final RelativeLayout rlPolievkaShowDialog=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlPolievkaButton);
    rlPolievkaShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}

private void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = DialogFragmentAlergeny.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

}

**DialogFragmentAlergeny:**

```
public class DialogFragmentAlergeny extends DialogFragment {

public static DialogFragmentAlergeny newInstance() {
    DialogFragmentAlergeny frag = new DialogFragmentAlergeny();
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alergeny_dialog, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.alergeny_dialog_title));
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
```

}

Comment: HomeFragment is not a fragment but a FragmentActivity...change extends  class to Fragment

Comment: @phemt.latd post your comment as an answer (Maybe you could add a bit more of context)

Comment: yes I was try this option too but when extend Fragment then method getSupportFragmentManager() is not recognized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HomeFragment is not a fragment but a FragmentActivity...change extends class to Fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends FragmentActivity { ... }
```

Comment: es I was try this option too but when extend Fragment then method getSupportFragmentManager() is not recognized

Comment: you can use 'getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()' android developer guide specify that FragmentManager:  **Interface for interacting with Fragment objects inside of an Activity**

Comment: sorry but still not recognized. Its look like method newFragmen.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog"); has problem with this. I try too getActivity().getFragmentManager() but not work too. Here is scr: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y2qtoiy66ubttr/fragmentNotRecognized.PNG

Comment: MOve mouse on the blinked error and please write here you error.

Comment: There is error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjswffvcfji0k24/notRecognizedFrag.PNG I find this You should use

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
If that is still giving you problems, then makre sure that your Activity extends FragmentActivity. But I cannot exted FragmentActivity, Im extending Fragment

Comment: The activity that contains **HomeActivity** must extends  *android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity* the **HomeFragment** must extends *android.support.v4.app.Fragment* and *getActivity()* return an instance of type *Activity* you must cast it to *android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity* to can had visibility on method *getSupportFragmentManager()*

Comment: OK thx I fix it I will write post bellow how fix these problem for another users.

Answer (score 16):

How Fix it:

1. HomeFragment must extend Fragment
2. You must use/import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` everywhere where needed.
3. `newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");` use `getsupportManager` not `FragmentManager()`
4. Use  `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();` not `FragmentManager()`

Thats all thx all for help.