# Why is this Error showing "Incompatible Types." "Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment"?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, main-activity

So my issue is with my Android app Fragments `fragment=new SlideShow();` is in a switch, this fuctions the NavDrawer and these people had the same issue but none of these Solutions fixed my problem [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475581/incompatible-types-of-fragment) and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993348/cannot-convert-from-android-support-v4-app-fragment-to-android-app-fragment) also [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514002/error72-42-error-incompatible-types-fragmentactivity-cannot-be-converted-t)

You may see something in the code that I haven't. I will the Error as it shows!

I've tried adding imports and also switching implements and extends, nothing has worked and no one with the same issue as mien.

**Error:**

`Error:(176, 26) error: incompatible types: SlideShow cannot be converted to Fragment`

and

`Incompatible Types.
Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found: com.adobe.SlideShow`

*My Code Snippet:*

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.abode;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by Ryan Tarson on 3/23/2015.
*/
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    //old code
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    //experiment code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);


        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));

        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.side_bar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       /* int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }*/
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home: {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_settings:

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    private void selectItem(int position)
    {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragment=new SlideShow();


                break;

            case 1:
                fragment=new Beauty();


                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
//            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment/Assigned designated page.");
        }
        // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

}
```

Here is were the "Home" Page is this the `case 0;` is the Home tab!
**SlideShow.java**

```
package com.abode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
/**
 * Created by Ryan on 5/5/2015.
 */
public class SlideShow extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory  {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.homeslideshow);

        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onebig);
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.test, R.drawable.onebig,
    };

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.test, R.drawable.onebig,
    };

}
```

Comment: A fragment and an activity, albeit they look the same and do pretty much the same, are two different entities, and you cannot instantiate an Activity to be a fragment. If you wish SlideShow to be a fragment, it should extend Fragment instead of Activity

Comment: But `SlideShow` is `Activity`, how do you want to make a `Fragment` of it?

Comment: Also there is Fragment in the non support android. It's the old fragment class. The new one might be the one you need. Depends on your application and which spi levels you support

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slideshow is an Activity not a Fragment.  You'll either need to recreate it as a Fragment or use an intent to switch to it.  You could do something like:

```
case 0:
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Slideshow.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   return;
```